# Anyone using vis.js with AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, chap-links-library

I'm trying to use [vis.js](http://visjs.org/) with AngularJS. It's working fine, I built a simple directive... 
But I need to use some of the events listed [here](http://visjs.org/docs/graph.html#Events), but they are not being fired.

In this example the `graph.on('select', ...)` event listener is not fired, there's any problem on how I'm doing this?

Here is what I'm doing:

```
    app.directive('visGraph', [function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            scope: {
                data: '=data',
                options: '=options'
            },
            link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

                var container = element[0];

                var graph = null;
                    graph = new vis.Graph(container, scope.data, scope.options);


                scope.$watch(function() {
                    return scope.data; 
                }, function(value) {
                    graph = new vis.Graph(container, scope.data, scope.options);
                });

                graph.on('select', function (properties) {
                    console.info('select.properties.nodes', properties.nodes);
                    console.info('select.properties.edges', properties.edges);
                });

            }
        };
    }]);
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: Could you add your .html and controller code maybe in a JSfiddle? I'm interested in this problem and working on it right now.

Comment: Great! As soon as possible I'm going to publish it in a JSfiddle. Can you share what do you have right now? If you agree, we could do an AngularJS wrapper for vis.js with the directive I built and with whatever you have and then we could put it on GitHub? What do you say?

Comment: Unfortunately this is work code so I can't disclose it, but I'd be interested in contributing to a AngularJS wrapper on Github! My problem right now is that if I use a directive like yours it doesn't work because the DOM is not loaded (it's in a ng-switch-when element). I'm trying to figure this out. Right now I've put all the code in the controller including a getElementById for the container which works well, even for graph.on events, but I know I'm not supposed to manipulate the DOM like this in an angularJS controller.

Comment: I feel like I should clarify : I have to wait for asynchronously fetched data to build my graph (fetched with $resource in my controller).

Comment: My graph is also built with asynchronously fetched data and I have the element which is using 'visGraph' directive on a 'ng-switch-when' and it is working just fine.. only their event listener are not being fired.

Comment: Well I solved my problem too you're right, but with my offered solution events are fired :)

Answer (score 2):

I just solved this problem. In my example, double-clicking on a node redirects to the node details. I just transfered the data and options to my controller. This code is compiled from Coffeescript so it's not the most perfect JS :

```
angular.module("myApp.directives").directive("visGraph", function($timeout, $window) {
  return {
    restrict: "AE",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var buildGraph;
      buildGraph = function(scope, element) {
        var container, graph;
        container = element[0];
        graph = null;
        graph = new vis.Graph(container, scope.data, scope.options);
        return graph.on('doubleClick', function(properties) {
          if (properties.nodes.length !== 0) {
            return $window.location = FRONTEND_URL + properties.nodes;
          }
        });
      };
      // Wait for data asynchronously with $resource in the controller
      scope.$watch('data', function(newval, oldval) {
        buildGraph(scope, element);
      }, true);
    }
  };
});
```

In your controller, define `$scope.data` and `$scope.options`.
In your markup you can then just add `vis-graph`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: What happens when the '$window.location' is called? Does your view updates too?

Comment: Yes, the view change to the specified URL.

Comment: and in that moment are you redrawing the graph? The 'properties.nodes' that you are passing on '$window.location' are you accessing them through the '$routeParams' or what are you doing with them after you redirect ?

Comment: When I built my graph I made sure that properties.nodes are ids, that's why I can redirect to "#resource/:resourceId" for instance. After landing I don't need them anymore and I'm drawing a different graph.

Comment: I did some work (simple) on this... So, I have just mixed your code with mine... and I got this working without the need to redirect the data to the controller. Basically, I have added the possibility of telling the directive which event I want to trigger on vis graph and a callback function for calling a controller function from inside the directive. I have created a [repo](https://github.com/edgaraafelix/angular-visgraph) on GitHub with my directive and a simple usage example. Feel free to take a look!

Answer (score 1):

I did some work (simple) on this... So, I have just mixed your code with mine... and I got this working without the need to redirect the data to the controller.

Basically, I have added the possibility of telling the directive which event I want to trigger on vis graph and a callback function for calling a controller function from inside the directive:

```
<div id="graph" vis-graph data="graph.data" options="graph.options" event="select" callback="callbackFunction(params)"></div>
```

I have created a [repo](https://github.com/edgaraafelix/angular-visgraph) on GitHub with my directive and a simple usage example.

Feel free to take a look!